# drupal 7 from mysql/apache to IIS/oracle

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Can anyone explain me the easy and step by step procedure to move the drupal7 existing website to IIS server and Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle isn't supported by Drupal 7 by default. However, in Drupal 7 the database layer has been abstracted and there are [some projects](http://groups.drupal.org/node/24398) that implement an Oracle driver.

To move your site to IIS you'll need to install PHP on it first. I recommend installing it the (new) [FastCGI way](http://php.iis.net/). Depending on the version of IIS you could use [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/?gclid=CLHR_vS4y6kCFZRX4Qod5jX6MA) or [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) (Microsoft) for URL rewriting. More information on URL rewriting in IIS for see the Drupal page: ["Clean URLs with IIS"](https://drupal.org/node/3854)

Moving an existing site might be more difficult. You'll need to backup, restore and assign the right permissions to the files. The recommended way of moving data to your Oracle database would by via [Oracle Migration Workbench](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+Migration+Workbench).

Comment: The Oracle driver can be found at http://drupal.org/project/oracle